# How to create a .txt file in sas using the palote character as delimiter?

Tags: sas

I am trying to create a .txt file with the delimiter '|' as delimiter, I am using a data step and inside the FILE statement I have been trying the DLM parameter and also DELIMITER, but none of them generate a .txt file with the delimiter as I want. The .txt file that is being created is not having any delimiter. This is the code I am using:

```
DATA OutputAC.XGFintra;
SET XGFintra;
FILE "&out_XGFintra." dlm='|' LRECL=32767 ;
PUT 
tip_doc $1.
num_doc $11.
banco $4.
cod_cliente $8.
nombre $26.
cod_unid $1.
descrip_unid $8.
moned_orig $3.
moned_dest $3.
tip_certif $1.
nomb_auditor $60.
cod_usu $8.
fec_ingreso $10.
fec_mod $10.
statement_id $10.
archive_id $10.
tip_balance $1.
cod_modelo $4.
cod_mod_herr $4.
cod_analisis_herr $4.
escala_corta $5.
escala_larga $5.
qnu_puntuac $17.
fec_ejerc $10.
imp_vol_ventas $17.
fec_ejerc_matr $10.
imp_vol_matriz $17.;
run;
```

You may wonder why I have not used a PROC EXPORT step, and I have, but the problem with PROC EXPORT is that it removes the whitespace that some variables have, and I am using the DATA step so that this does not happen, as I must necessarily have some variables with whitespace on the left or on the right.
Does anyone have any suggestions?
Thank you very much.

Comment: If you're using PUT it puts only what you've specified and you're not specifying your delimiter here. Can you define your requirements a bit more, it somewhat seems like you may want to explore a fixed width file?

Comment: The variables do have a fixed width, but the file can have a non-fixed width, because the sticks will generate an increase in the width of the file.
I don't quite understand when you say I'm not specifying the delimiter, do you have an example I can use to guide me?. Muchas gracias.

Comment: When you specify PUT, it only writes exactly what you tell it to, as coded. In this case you need to put the delimiter in the PUT statement as well. There are some shortcut methods, but I think they'll all strip the spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use list mode to have SAS insert the delimiters. But to make a delimited file you should really use the DSD option on the FILE statement. When you do that SAS will insure that the delimited file is properly formatted to allow the lines to be parsed by adding quotes around values that contain the delimiter.  Plus it will not waste any characters to represent empty values.

```
DATA OutputAC.XGFintra;
  SET XGFintra;
  FILE "&out_XGFintra." dsd dlm='|' LRECL=32767 ;
  PUT 
    tip_doc 
    num_doc 
    banco 
    cod_cliente 
    nombre 
    cod_unid
    descrip_unid
    moned_orig 
    moned_dest 
    tip_certif
    nomb_auditor
    cod_usu
    fec_ingreso
    fec_mod
    statement_id
    archive_id
    tip_balance
    cod_modelo
    cod_mod_herr
    cod_analisis_herr
    escala_corta
    escala_larga
    qnu_puntuac
    fec_ejerc 
    imp_vol_ventas
    fec_ejerc_matr
    imp_vol_matriz
  ;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up two different kinds of output here, which is causing your issue.

Generally we have "fixed width" files and "delimited" files, and we don't generally have files that are both (fields of fixed width but also delimited).  I suppose you could if you really wanted to, but it sort of defeats the point of the delimiter.

When you do this:

```
put var $15.;
```

It will not use your delimiter, because delimiters are only put when you use `list` output.  This is not `list` - this is `formatted`, and that assumes fixed-width output.

You can use `modified list` output, though, see the following example:

filename f temp;

```
data _null_;
  set sashelp.class;
  file f dlm='|';
  put age :6.  
      name :$20.
  ;
run;

data _null_;
  infile f;
  input @;
  put _infile_;
run;
```

However, this does not preserve spaces the way you seem to want.  For that, you'll have to actually use formatted input and put your own characters in.
filename f temp;

```
data _null_;
  set sashelp.class;
  file f;
  put age 6. '|'  
      name $20. '|'
  ;
run;

data _null_;
  infile f;
  input @;
  put _infile_;
run;
```

You can see more on this and the difference in the [sas documentation on PUT](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.5&docsetId=lestmtsref&docsetTarget=p0jcwhe1ofmb49n1xf1q2kc44b0v.htm&locale=en).

Comment: Thank you so much, your advice has helped me a lot, thank you!!!